# Error: encoding GBK's unmapped characters

Tags: java, android

```
builder.put("XAU", "Gold");
builder.put("XCD", "East Caribbean Dollar");
builder.put("XDR", "Special Drawing Rights");
builder.put("XOF", "CFA Franc BCEAO");
builder.put("XPF", "CFP Franc");
builder.put("YER", "Yemeni Rial");
builder.put("ZAR", "South African Rand");
builder.put("ZMK", "Zambian Kwacha (1968–2012)");
builder.put("ZMW", "Zambian Kwacha");
builder.put("ZWL", "Zimbabwean Dollar (2009)");
```

1.I Click the error and it skip to "Zambian Kwacha (1968–2012)"
    ***I have try to add below code to build.gradle

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}
```

2.and also I change Android Studio of File Encoding to UTF-8,
    but above were both fail. how can i do to solve this?